# Python circular dependency issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import

```
 Dir->   test
           |_foo
             |__init__.py
              __a.py
              __b.py

**init.py**

 import os
 from test.foo.a import begin

 class Behaviour("some inherited class"):
   def good():
       print "good"
   def bad():
      begin()
 foo = Behaviour()
```

---

```
a.py

from . import foo

def end():
    print "running"
    foo.good()

def begin():
 print "begin"
```

---

when__init__.py get called I am seeing error:

```
     test/foo/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>

     from test.foo.a import begin

     File "/test/foo/a.py", line 17, in <module>

     from . import foo

     ImportError: cannot import name api
```

Seems like i am hitting circular dependency issue here.Can someone please help me how to resolve it?

Comment: If `begin` is only needed in `bad()` (or at least seldom needed) move the import into `bad()` (and possibly other needing functions). Edit: Better do that with the `foo` import in `a.py` if possible.

Comment: @MichaelButscher begin function is used at lot of places in code base and if i move it to __init__.py then i would end up potentially be breaking othe part of code base.That's why i am reluctant to move the "begin" into __init__.py

Comment: Ugly and I'm not even sure if it works: Move the imports to the end of the files.

Comment: Another option would be to avoid importing names out of modules but only importing modules like `from test.foo import a` and then using `a.begin()` everywhere.

Comment: @MichaelButscher That does not work too.It gives the same error.I think i can move the begin() func into __init__.py but then how would i import begin function if i needed t call it in different directory then "foo"

Comment: You could move definition of `Behaviour` and `foo` in a `c.py` and, as said, only import modules `a` in `c` and `c` in `a` and use names like `a.begin()` in the code.